# How to set node.js cron job for make somthing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

How can i make a function every 2 second in node.js?

until now, i found [this](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) repository that can do cron job..

server.js:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Procfile:

```
web: node server.js
```

there is another recommended way?

Comment: probably try this tool, I find it quite useful for generate simple cron express...http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: nice tool, but with this tool you can not set second, so it does not solved my problem.

Comment: can i just ask why you need to run something every 2 seconds ? There could be a better approach.. I mean you could just go for a `setInterval` ? http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.1/api/timers.html

Comment: because i make http request for another server that return me data, this data can change every second, and my app need to be update every time.

Comment: it might be better to post from the updating server then and have your node server just accept the incoming data.. Would seem a more reliable approach. If you don't have access to the other server, then crawling a remote dataSource everysecond for updates.. I would ensure the searching thread is seperate to that of the node server to avoid weird threading problems down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

new CronJob('*/2 * * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every two second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if this will solve your problem but your initial Q was

> How can i make a function every 2 second in node.js?

So you can use `setInterval`like so :

```
function runMe() {
      console.log('You will see this message every two seconds');
}

//Run ever 2 seconds
setInterval(runMe, 2000);
```

This will do what you're looking for in your example.

Answer (score 2):

I use the module **schedule** and I am happy with the outcome. The code goes like this:

```
var every = require('schedule').every;

every('2s').do(function() {
console.log("You will see this message every second")
}
```